# How I can uncheck checkbox when both of my inputs [type=text] cleared or empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, function

How I can uncheck `input` of type **checkbox** when both of my `input`s of type **text** are empty, and checked if one of my `input`s of type **text** is filled?

```js
$('input[name="t2"],input[name="t3"]').keyup(function() {
  $('input[name="t1"]').prop("checked", $.trim($(this).val()).length != 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="t1" /> Price range from:
<input type="text" name="t2" /> to <input type="text" name="t2" />
```

JSFiddle : [here in this link](http://jsfiddle.net/r03uakqx/)

It executes correctly when I type something on any input type text(checkbox checked), but not working when I clear both of fields, because the checkbox unchecked when only one of inputs clear.
Would you please help me solve this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are triggering twice. You simply need to check if any of the two fields has input. Like this:

```
$('input[name="t2"],input[name="t3"]').keyup(function () {           
      $('input[name="t1"]').prop("checked",
        //now check if any of the two inputs have content
        $.trim($('input[name="t2"]').val()).length != 0 ||
        $.trim($('input[name="t3"]').val()).length != 0
       );
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it this way, you get the value of each input. If both are empty you uncheck, if one is filled you check the box.

```js
$('input[name="t2"],input[name="t3"]').keyup(function() {
  var t2 = $('input[name="t2"]').val();
  var t3 = $('input[name="t3"]').val();
  if (t2 != "" || t3 != "") {
    $('input[name="t1"]').prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $('input[name="t1"]').prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' name='t1'>
<input type="text" name="t2">
<input type="text" name="t3">
```

Comment: This is right, so let me explain more about its context,  I have a table of treatment prices for a medical issue, each row dedicate to one treatment, and in each row I have three inpust, 1- checkbox for highlighting and selecting any treatment (to be include in their list of services )
2 & 3-two inputs=text for adding price range min and max to each treatment row, 

the question is how I can call elements of each row separately, because t1,t2 and t3 repeats in each rows. Would you please tell me more?